# Preventing registered users from sharing email/password login credentials in Firebase

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm using email/password as an authentication method in Firebase (React Native) and cannot find any documentation on how to prevent credentials being shared amongst users. It seems multiple users can use the same credentials on multiple devices simultaneously.

How can i prevent this to prevent users sharing an account credentials and logging in simultaneously on multiple devices?

Thanks

Comment: Preventing the same credentials from signing in on multiple devices is (by design) not a feature of Firebase Authentication. How to implement it yourself has been covered multiple times though, so I recommend checking on those questions. https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+authentication+limit+to+single+device